# Different index.html with angular

Tags: angular, authentication

When the user load the app, the server checks if he is allowed to access it. 
If not, I would like to redirect it to an error page.

Relevant code from index.html I

```
 <app-root></app-root>
```

main.ts

```
   platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

The AppModule includes inside it the routes for the lazy load modules, and when I try to access an url, it begin to build the routes although I am not authorized.

The authorization check occurs here:

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
...
providers:[
{
provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
**useFactory: startupServiceFactory,**
...
}
]

**startupServiceFactory**(){
return () => startupService.load();
}
```

Could I redirect the user to an error page ?

Comment: Can you provide your routes and the appmodule code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make check using `canActivate` of Angular like this -

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: yourComponent,
    canActivate: [ AuthGuardService ]
  }
```

Here `AuthGuardService` is your service where you can check whether user is authorized or not and redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am prefare to make this in backend ...
 if is authenticated : I am calling this view " "
if not : calling another view

and you can make this solution on the same page

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ( true) {
  document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = 
  "<AppRoot>Loading ...</AppRoot>";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> aaaaaa</div>
<div id="main">  </div>
```

If you want make permissions on angular routes you can add

```
     {
    path: 'abc',
    component: abcComponent,
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
          data: {
              roles: ['admin'] ,
        },
 { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
  }
```

and type your code of AuthGuard As you want:

```
 @Injectable()

  export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor( private router: Router) { }

   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

  //    let roles = route.data["roles"] as Array<string>;
      if (role Condition)
          return true;
      else
        {
  this.router.navigateByUrl("/notfound");
//return false;
}  

    }
  }
```